# Flutter Response issue

Tags: laravel, api, android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I m having very strange issues in flutter,
i have  a function in flutter which is calling api, it work perfectly but sometime it throw error,and app paused the app, Here is my function  fluter function and also the api which i m calling,

```
//this is my flutter function work fine,but sometime it thow this error
```

Error:Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError (Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null),  the error ocure on this line

//on this line  if(body['success']){//

```
Future countcartdata() async {
  var count=0;
   SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String identifier = sharedPrefs.getString('identifier');
     final String url = ApiUtility.Main_Url+ApiUtility.countcart+'identifier='+identifier;
     var res=await http .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
       var body = json.decode(res.body);
      if(body['success']){
       print(url);
         count=body['coutcart'];
        if(count>0){
         sharedPrefs.setString('carthasdata','yes');
         return count;
          }
          else{
          sharedPrefs.setString('carthasdata','no');
          return count=0;
          }
     }
     return count;
    }
```

this is my api function mean it will always return success true,,,because i have used the count method,please help,,,my app run smoothly but suddenly stop working,even hang my mobile ,so i have to reboot then it will work,,,

```
public function countcart(Request $request){
      $identifier=$request->identifier;   
      $coutcart=Restcart::where('identifier',$identifier)->count();
      return Response::json(array(
      'coutcart' => $coutcart,
      'success' => true,
       )); 
      }
```

Comment: If network goes you won't be getting that response and there will be an error in your if (body['success']) case. You didn't coded for the error cases that can happen. Try to think about the error cases also.

Comment: How can you hint please,,,,as i m checking if not success true,, then i juts return count 0, that's it

Comment: In that response you'll get http status code also, you can check that. Check whether the body is of correct type etc

Comment: Yes thanks,, i was runing stream and the request rate was limited in laravel,apis,so after 60 request laravel was returning other status code,,i handle that